# How to make lazyload plugin work with datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables, lazy-loading, jquery-events, jquery-lazyload

I have a datatable which has images in one of its columns.

The amount of rows reaches 900+ and I want to avoid the browser trying to load 900+ images given the resources it uses and the time it takes to load the page.

That's where the lazyload plugin seems to come as a rescue !!
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

The first page loads fine, but the images do not load when :

1. User clicks on the "next" button to view the next page
2. User filters and a particular row is shown

I see that there is a section for "Event trigger loading" on the lazy load plugin, but I'm not sure how I can use it.

Would be great if someone can point me in the right direction.

Note : By Datatables, I mean http://www.datatables.net

Edit : 8/27 - Forgot about this question. But I ended up implementing my own custom solution :)

Comment: Can you please show your custom solution?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [DataTables server-side processing with pipelining example](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html)?

Here the author gave a solution of lazy loading data using pipelining.